# How to retrieve a lot of objects in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, heap-memory

**What I need to do:**

I need to export a huge amount (undetermined size) of data to CSV from MongoDB according to a date range. (Minimum is a day and there's no maximum)

The amount of data is different between each days.

**My problems:**

I thought about using `mongoexport` but I need to add columns that doesn't exist in the DB.

My MongoDB objects are not huge individually, they are composed with texts only but I have a lot of them in the database and need to retrieve a lot of them. So when I am using Mongo through NodeJS to query my objects, I have:

> JavaScript heap out of memory

I am searching a long-term solution that will allow me not to worry about how many days of data I am trying to retrieve.

Any solution(s)?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use [cursor.stream](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html#stream) and [csv-write-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-write-stream) to create something like this:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream');
var fs = require('fs');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function (err, db) {
    var collection = db.collection('big_collection');
    var stream = collection.find().stream();
    var writer = csvWriter();
    writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.csv'));
    stream.on('end', function () {
        writer.destroy();
        db.close();
    });
    stream.on('data', function (data) {
        Object.assign(data, {'some_extra_column' : ''});
    });
    stream.pipe(writer);
});
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunately still having a "JavaScript heap out of memory".